# I need the message "the button is pressed how many times" to be displayed when clicking on the button in the discord bot

Tags: python, discord

```
class Baton(disnake.ui.View):
  def __init__(self):
      global start_time
      super().__init__(timeout=None)
      self.value: Optional[bool] = None
  # Когда кнопка подтверждения нажата, установите внутреннее значение на «Истина» 
  # остановить  от большего количества ввода.
  @disnake.ui.button(label="Забрать код ", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.green)
  async def first(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    winner = button.
    await inter.response.send_message(f"{winner} нажал первый")
    self.value = True
    self.stop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.